# mxnet: parameters are always on CPU

Tags: deep-learning, mxnet

When using mxnet, after building and training a module `mod`, I called the method `mod.get_params()` to inspect the weights and bias of the model.

However, I found that even if I set the context to `mx.gpu(0)` when creating the module, the outputs of the `get_params` method always show that the parameters (weights and bias) are on `cpu(0)`. See below:

[image: results of get_params]

I wonder whether the weights were really on cpu, so I timed the program and found that, it was in fact much faster if I set the context to `gpu(0)` than to `cpu(0)`. Therefore, I think the weights were in fact on gpu, otherwise the training wouldn't be so fast. But, why did the `get_params` method show that my weights were on cpu?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `mod.get_params` synchronizes the parameters in GPU memory, with a copy that is placed in CPU memory. You're seeing the copy, that's in the cpu context, so there's no need for concern.

Under the hood, `_sync_params_from_devices` is called if the parameters are 'dirty' (i.e. out of sync); where 'device' is GPU(s).